# Mysql обьединение записей

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица:

```
id     data      id_name  type
1  15.04.2019 15  144      1
2  15.04.2019 16  154      2
3  15.04.2019 17  144      1
4  15.04.2019 16  154      2
```

Как мне можно обьединить повторяющиеся строки в таблицу по дате, а также удалить повторяющиеся и сделать 1 запись вместо повторяющихся, и пятым параметром sum запихнуть количество повторяющихся строк.

```
id     data    id_name   type sum
 1  15.04.2019  144        1   2
 2  15.04.2019  154        2   2
```

Чтоб в итоге в таблице остались 2 записи. Сортировка будет только по дню, часы будут откидываться.

Буду благодарен за любую идею, помощь.

Comment: *Чтоб в итоге в таблице остались 2 записи* Ну так покажите нужный результат - те самые две оставшиеся записи.

Comment: @Akina показал пример

Comment: Теперь вменяемо объясните, почему именно id=1 и 2 оставлены, а остальные удалены. А заодно - что это за необозначенное поле со значениями 15..17? И уж сразу, чтобы два раза не бегать - укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: Это новая таблица в которой совпадения удаленны и в ведена 5 колонка где написано сколько было совпадений

Comment: Мля... Между полем data и полем id_name присутствует безымянная колонка. ЧТО ЭТО ???

Comment: Поправил уже это были часы в колонке data в старой таблице вывод число месяц год час

Comment: Ок. Теперь - почему записи 1 и 2 оставлены, а 3 и 4 удалены? Вернее, почему в результат попали именно эти значения `id` (а по большому счёту - нахрена они там вообще нужны, эти `id`)? И всё же укажите версию MySQL.

Comment: Id авто инкримент, записи  удалены потому что поле id_name повторялось это делается чтобы облекчить размер таблицы

Comment: Я спросил не почему удалены, а почему удалены **ИМЕННО ЭТИ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ**. И всё же укажите версию MySQL.

Comment: У меня есть база статистики пользователь заходит на смотрит серию манги аниме с кажды заходом добовляется по 1 записи сейчас их стало очень большое количество чтобы облегчить базу нужно брать 1 день брать записи совпадаюшие по id_name соединять в 1 запись и добавить 5 колонку в которой количество удаленных повторяюшихся записей

Comment: Версия mysql 5.7

Comment: Ладно, не хотите объяснять, почему ТАКОЙ выбор - не надо, не мои проблемы. Последний вопрос - а что всё-таки требуется? Варианты: 1) получить показанный результат запросом; 2) удалить из исходной таблицы не показанные в результате данные.

Comment: Удалить из исходной таблицы непоказаные результаты и добавить 5 параметр сколько удаленно повторяюшихся записей

Comment: Это делается в три запроса. Первый - добавит поле. Второй - обновит записи с минимальным id за день, вставит туда количество записей. Третий - удалит записи, у которых поле не обновлено.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- создать поле
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD COLUMN summ INT DEFAULT NULL;

-- посчитать количества    
UPDATE mytable, (SELECT MIN(id) id, COUNT(*) summ, DATE(data) data
                 FROM mytable
                 GROUP BY DATE(data), id_name, type) sq
SET mytable.summ = sq.summ,
    mytable.data = sq.data
WHERE mytable.id = sq.id;

-- удалить лишнее
DELETE
FROM mytable
WHERE summ IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Заранее прошу прощения но я не силен в синтаксисе MySQL

если нужна просто выборка, то все решается с помощью группировки:

```
SELECT data,  id_name, type, COUNT(*)   as sum
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY data, id_name, type
```

если вам необходимо удалить запись которая повторяется, то можно добавить к таблице триггер `before insert`
и прописать условие нахождения похожей записи и апдейта поля `sum` у этой записи

[статья про триггеры](http://www.rldp.ru/mysql/mysqlpro/triggers.htm)

Comment: эх 5 баллов не хватает для писания в комментарии

Comment: *если нужна просто выборка* Нет, читайте комментарии. *можно добавить к таблице триггер* В триггере такие операции недопустимы.

Comment: @Akina, значит выход это процедура которая отрабатывает через n-ый промежуток времени , и всё таки почему они не допустимы в триггере, можно по подробнее, чтобы в будущем на такие грабли не наступать

Comment: ага я понял, моё решение с триггером только для новых данных, на старых это никак не отразится

Comment: Не в том дело. Триггер не может изменять данные в таблице, событие на которой его запустило. Ибо потенциально это может привести к зацикливанию - ведь выполненное изменение вызовет срабатывание триггера, который вызовет изменение, которое ... и так далее.

Comment: Error number: 1442; Message: Can't update table '%s' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: @Akina, ясно, mysql лочит таблицу на время работы с триггером и не дает менять данные в этой же таблице. ну что же,узнал что-то новое -  день прожит не зря :D